# How to crop a specific object from a picture using python?

Tags: python, image-processing

[character](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=80D6D99AFF068BF7!3816&authkey=!ABjISav45jnSrqI&v=3&ithint=photo,.bmp)

Hello, I'm new in python,and recently I'm using python to do some image processing.The picture(link) above have some Chinese Characters.Here's the question:how can I crop every single character from the picture into a new picture? In other word,I want get several pictures like what (link) shows below:

[goal](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=80D6D99AFF068BF7!3815&authkey=!AD3adURY3P7XKcA&v=3&ithint=photo,.png)

The point is I want a program of python can automatically detect where to crop.And I really appreciate anyone could help me with it.

Comment: I don't know if you need to "automatically detect where to crop"- that could be quite difficult. Hopefully the images will have some kind of grid structure to them, so you can just e.g. split the image up into 200x200 pixel squares to get the individual characters?

Comment: If the input images are of going to be same size and the font in it would be same then you can crop it by fixing fixed crop size for every input image. PIL is one of the python library for image processing. http://www.riisen.dk/dop/pil.html

Answer (score 0):

Because each kanji are in separated rows and column, you can simply cut with a fixed length.

If you want to detect it dynamically there are many simple ways :

- Using vertical and horizontal projection. Then with the histograms you can find where are the histograms.

[image]

- Using [mathematical morphology such as dilatation/erosion (closing)](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/09/07/almost-connected-component-labeling/) or using RLSA in order to merge connected components. Then with bounding box of connected component you can find precisely the position of each kanji.